# How can I be better my code to find out the length of a list?

Tags: haskell, recursion, compiler-errors

I'm doing a code to find out the length of a list, using recursion, but there is a lot of error. I'm a very beginner and I can't very well Haskell.
Here is the code:

```
longListe :: [a] -> a

longListe [] = error "Empty liste"
longListe [x]= 1
longListe n = 1 + longListe (n-1)
main = print $ longListe
```

and the errors:

```
 No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of
        the type signature for longListe :: [a] -> a
    In the expression: 1
    In an equation for ‘longListe’: longListe [x] = 1

4-1-a.hs:6:31:
    No instance for (Num [a]) arising from a use of ‘-’
    In the first argument of ‘longListe’, namely ‘(n - 1)’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘longListe (n - 1)’
    In the expression: 1 + longListe (n - 1)

4-1-a.hs:7:8:
    No instance for (Show ([a0] -> a0))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In the expression: print
    In the expression: print $ longListe
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ longListe
```

can somebody please help me. Thanks

Comment: One problem: you are doing `(n-1)` where `n`is a list. You can not perform integer operations on a list.

Comment: Why should `longListe` raise an error instead of returning 0 for an empty list?

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in the type definition of your function: `longListe :: [a] -> a`.

It works fine if you call `longListe` on a list of number. For example, if you call `longListe [1,2,3]`, the typing will be `[Int] -> Int`.

However, if you try to get the length of a list of strings, this type becomes `[String] -> String`. This is **not** what you want, since you want to return a number.

The errors you get indicate that:

> No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’

Since you return a number and do numeric operations with you input, the compiler expects `a` to be a number hence the error mentioning `(Num a)`.

If you change the definition to `longListe :: [a] -> Int`, it should work better (actually it still won't work but for a different reason, but I'll let you try to resolve this yourself since this is the best way to learn).

Also, is there any reason why the empty list should error instead of returning 0?

Comment: 4-1-a.hs:3:16:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the expression: "Empty liste"
    In an equation for ‘longListe’: longListe [] = "Empty liste"

4-1-a.hs:6:8:
    No instance for (Show ([a0] -> Int))
      (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In the expression: print
    In the expression: print $ longListe
    In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ longListe
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: @posh I assume you removed `error` in `longListe [] = error "Empty liste"`. You now have a discrepancy between your return types. Sometimes you return a number, sometime a string (`[Char]` is equivalent to `String`). You need to make sure that the values you return are always of the same type.